# Removing Characters before exclamatory mark in a String

Tags: java

Please let me know how can i remove words before exclamatory mark .

Means for example if the Sring is

```
BIM!A  , i need only A 

SAM!B   , i need only B 

SNNJ!D  , I need only D
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("!")+1);
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT: link to javadoc: [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) and [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: which part will be returned?

Comment: @awolfe91, added links to the javadoc, hope you don't mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("!") + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a search within a `String` with

```
Strings s = "ABD!A";
//This gives you the index of the first !
int i = s.indexOf('!');
//now you can Substring 
String after = s.substring(i+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(str.substring(s.lastIndexOf("!") + 1));
```

This will print portion of string which is present after the last exclamation mark. Prints the whole string if no "!" is there